# Mount a directory from a different host as a volume in mongo docker container

Tags: mongodb, docker

Suppose that I have a mongod instance that needs to read/write data from a directory on a remote host. Is there a way to either:

1. Mount directly the remote directory to the mongo container, or
2. Mount the remote directory to a local directory, and then mount that local directory to the Docker container?

In my case, suppose the remote directory that needs to be mounted is `/data/db`. My current approach for the 2nd option is as following:

- Create a mounting point in the VM that host the mongod instance. i.e: `/local/data/db`
- Mount the remote directory to local using `sshfs`:

```
sudo sshfs -o allow_other,defer_permissions,IdentityFile=/Users/<your_username>/.ssh/id_rsa <your_username>@<host_name>:/data/db /local/data/db
```

- Run the docker container:

```
docker run -p 27017:27017 -v /local/data/db:/data/db --name mongo mongo
```

Which obviously failed, I got the following error:

```
chown: changing ownership of '/data/db/._admin.ns': Operation not permitted
chown: changing ownership of '/data/db/diagnostic.data/._metrics.2020-03-19T08-42-17Z-00000': Operation not permitted
chown: changing ownership of '/data/db/diagnostic.data/._metrics.2020-03-19T07-58-39Z-00000': Operation not permitted
chown: changing ownership of '/data/db/diagnostic.data/._metrics.2020-03-31T04-00-13Z-00000': Operation not permitted
chown: changing ownership of '/data/db/diagnostic.data/._metrics.2020-02-15T15-52-17Z-00000': Operation not permitted
chown: changing ownership of '/data/db/diagnostic.data/._metrics.2020-03-19T07-13-47Z-00000': Operation not permitted
chown: changing ownership of '/data/db/diagnostic.data/._metrics.2020-04-06T23-03-58Z-00000': Operation not permitted
chown: changing ownership of '/data/db/diagnostic.data/._metrics.2020-03-19T08-34-46Z-00000': Operation not permitted
chown: changing ownership of '/data/db/diagnostic.data/._metrics.2020-02-17T23-37-17Z-00000': Operation not permitted
chown: changing ownership of '/data/db/diagnostic.data/._metrics.2020-03-21T18-30-13Z-00000': Operation not permitted
chown: changing ownership of '/data/db/diagnostic.data/._metrics.2020-04-02T12-20-13Z-00000': Operation not permitted
chown: changing ownership of '/data/db/diagnostic.data/._metrics.2020-02-24T19-57-21Z-00000': Operation not permitted
chown: changing ownership of '/data/db/diagnostic.data/._metrics.2020-11-03T13-34-09Z-00000': Operation not permitted
chown: changing ownership of '/data/db/diagnostic.data/._metrics.2020-11-05T21-24-09Z-00000': Operation not permitted
chown: changing ownership of '/data/db/diagnostic.data/._metrics.2020-04-04T18-21-07Z-00000': Operation not permitted
chown: changing ownership of '/data/db/diagnostic.data/._metrics.2020-03-18T10-49-27Z-00000': Operation not permitted
chown: changing ownership of '/data/db/diagnostic.data/._metrics.2020-10-29T22-24-37Z-00000': Operation not permitted
chown: changing ownership of '/data/db/diagnostic.data/._metrics.2020-03-19T08-24-02Z-00000': Operation not permitted
chown: changing ownership of '/data/db/diagnostic.data/._metrics.2020-02-13T08-32-17Z-00000': Operation not permitted
chown: changing ownership of '/data/db/diagnostic.data/._metrics.interim': Operation not permitted
chown: changing ownership of '/data/db/diagnostic.data/._metrics.2020-02-20T06-07-19Z-00000': Operation not permitted
chown: changing ownership of '/data/db/diagnostic.data/._metrics.2020-03-19T07-02-42Z-00000': Operation not permitted
chown: changing ownership of '/data/db/diagnostic.data/._metrics.2020-11-01T05-49-37Z-00000': Operation not permitted
chown: changing ownership of '/data/db/diagnostic.data/._metrics.2020-03-19T04-01-35Z-00000': Operation not permitted
chown: changing ownership of '/data/db/diagnostic.data/._metrics.2020-02-29T10-42-21Z-00000': Operation not permitted
chown: changing ownership of '/data/db/diagnostic.data/._metrics.2020-03-19T07-26-52Z-00000': Operation not permitted
chown: changing ownership of '/data/db/diagnostic.data/._metrics.2020-03-28T19-20-13Z-00000': Operation not permitted
chown: changing ownership of '/data/db/diagnostic.data/._metrics.2020-02-27T03-12-21Z-00000': Operation not permitted
chown: changing ownership of '/data/db/diagnostic.data/._metrics.2020-03-26T10-40-13Z-00000': Operation not permitted
chown: changing ownership of '/data/db/diagnostic.data/._metrics.2020-03-19T08-40-20Z-00000': Operation not permitted
chown: changing ownership of '/data/db/diagnostic.data/._metrics.2020-03-19T09-33-10Z-00000': Operation not permitted
chown: changing ownership of '/data/db/diagnostic.data/._metrics.2020-03-24T03-15-13Z-00000': Operation not permitted
chown: changing ownership of '/data/db/diagnostic.data/._metrics.2020-02-22T12-07-20Z-00000': Operation not permitted
chown: changing ownership of '/data/db/diagnostic.data/._metrics.2020-03-18T09-27-49Z-00000': Operation not permitted
chown: changing ownership of '/data/db/journal/._lsn': Operation not permitted
chown: changing ownership of '/data/db/journal/._j._2': Operation not permitted
chown: changing ownership of '/data/db/journal/._j._1': Operation not permitted
chown: changing ownership of '/data/db/journal/._prealloc.2': Operation not permitted
chown: changing ownership of '/data/db/._.': Operation not permitted
chown: changing ownership of '/data/db/._config.0': Operation not permitted
chown: changing ownership of '/data/db/._local.0': Operation not permitted
chown: changing ownership of '/data/db/._diagnostic.data': Operation not permitted
chown: changing ownership of '/data/db/._journal': Operation not permitted
chown: changing ownership of '/data/db/_tmp/._1586251487696721': Operation not permitted
chown: changing ownership of '/data/db/._config.ns': Operation not permitted
chown: changing ownership of '/data/db/._storage.bson': Operation not permitted
chown: changing ownership of '/data/db/._mongod.lock': Operation not permitted
chown: changing ownership of '/data/db/.__tmp': Operation not permitted
chown: changing ownership of '/data/db/._local.ns': Operation not permitted
chown: changing ownership of '/data/db/._admin.0': Operation not permitted
chown: changing ownership of '/data/db/._local.1': Operation not permitted
```

Answer (score 0):

You can mount a volume to your mongodb container that uses data on a remote machine, by using [`sshfs` volume driver](https://github.com/vieux/docker-volume-sshfs). [Here](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/#use-a-volume-driver) you can find official docker documentation and example of it.

To be able to use ssh keys, you need to install `sshfs` plugin like:

```
docker plugin install vieux/sshfs sshkey.source=/Users/<your_username>/.ssh/
```

You need to verify that SSH connection to the data hosting machine is available. If it's so, you can create volume like:

```
docker volume create \
  -d vieux/sshfs \
  -o sshcmd=<user>@<host>/data/db \
  -o IdentityFile=/Users/<your_username>/.ssh/id_rsa
  mongodata
```

Then you will be able to mount this volume like:

```
docker run -d \
  -p 27017:27017 \  
  -v mongodata:/data/db \
  --name mongo \
  mongo
```

If you face errors again, I highly suggest you to figure out your keys usage. You can find more info [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/61567/how-to-specify-key-in-sshfs/61572).